# Domain of function $\{\sqrt{x}\}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the domain of the function :
$\{\sqrt{x}\}^2$
my answer is if we are consrained to the real numbers the domain will be 
$\left[0,\inf\right)$
but if we are allowed use the complex numbers the domain will be R

Comment: That is correct

Comment: domain will be C was meant I guess

Comment: Isn't the square root function ill-defined in the complex plane, as 'picking the positive one' isn't always possible anymore?

Comment: If you are allowed to use complex numbers the domain will be the complex plane unless a half line.

Comment: I dont think most precalculus classes deal with functions in the complex plane and i think the square root of the complex plane isn't well defined @keoxkeox

Comment: "Isn't the square root function ill-defined in the complex plane, as 'picking the positive one' isn't always possible anymore?"  Yes and no.  You can just as easily define the square root as 'pick the one with non-negative real part, but if real part is 0 pick the one with nonreal imaginary part' and it'd be just as well-defined.  And just as arbitrary.  We can do this but we don't usally bother as it just isn't as useful any more to pick an arbitrary root.  Indeed knowing the multiple roots is *more* useful.  We are grown-ups now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is a required part defining a function (albeit often implicit) so the domain is whatever you say it is.

Perhaps the the question should be what is the most all encompassing possible domain.  That depends on what the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ is.

If $\sqrt{x}$ is defined as: $c$ so that $c^2 = x$, then the largest possible domain is $\{0\}$ .  Is is because: $c$ so that $c^2 = x$ is only well, and uniquely defined if $x = 0$.  For any other value of $x$ there will be two possible values of $c$ and the "function" is not well-defined.

If $\sqrt{x}$ is defined as: $c$ so that $c^2 = x$, and $c$ is the non-negative square root.  Then the assumption is that $x$ has two square roots of which one is positive and the other is negative.  This implies that $x$ is a non-negative real number so the domain is $(0,\infty)$.

If $\sqrt{x}$ is: $c$ so that $c^2 = x$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ and $c \in (0, \infty)$ if $x \ge 0$ and $c = ai|a \in (0, \infty)$ if $x < 0$. Then the domain is $\mathbb R$.

But that is because we *SAID* $x \in \mathbb R$.

If we define $\sqrt{x}$ as: $c $ so that $c^2 = x$ and $x \in \mathbb C$ and $c \in \mathbb C$ so that $c = a + bi;$ and $a \ge 0$.  Then the domain is $\mathbb C$.  But again, that is because we *said* it was.

==== 2nd answer =====

The question as asked has two problems in how it is asked and what assumptions are being made in the asking of the question.

1) A function must have the domain either explicitly or implicitly stated as part of the definition of a function.

A function is defined as $f: X \rightarrow Y$ where the function is a mapping between pairs of values of $X$ and values of $Y$ where each and every value of $X$ (the domain) is mapped, *exactly once*, to multiples of $Y$.  (Not every value of $Y$ needs to be mapped to, and a value of $Y$ may be mapped to several times but every value of $X$ must be mapped from and can only be mapped from once).

By definition, the domain $X$ is a specific part of $f$ and so to say "what is the domain of $f$" is simply a matter of well, what did you *define* the domain to be?"

However the domain may be implicit and not explicitly stated.  If $f(n) = \frac n2 - 7$ and its understood we are mapping natural numbers to natural numbers, It's not possible for *any* natural number to be input.  An odd number will not be mapped to any natural number.  Any number $14$ or less won't be mapped into a natural number either.  So implicitly the domain is $\{n \in \mathbb N: 2\mid n; n > 14\}$.

Here we aren't told anything about what the input and output of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ are  supposed to be.  Are the supposed to be natural numbers?  Integers?  Rationals?  Reals?  Complex?  A  vector space? The space of functions?  Bananas?

2) $\sqrt{x} = $ "the square root of $x$" is  ill-defined.  i) Depending upon what the output is supposed to be the input/domain is restricted.  If the output must be natural numbers the input must be a perfect square.  If the output must be real then input must be real non-negative.  ii) Given a domain of input there may be multiple options for the output.  e.g. The square root of 36 could be 6 or -6.  The square root of $-25$ could be 5i or $-5i$.  The square root of $i$ could be $\frac {\sqrt 2}2 + i \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$ or $ - \frac {\sqrt 2}2 - i\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$. etc.

And the thing is if we define with square root to "pick" we are implicitly indicating what the domain is.  If we say $\sqrt x$ is "the positive one" that implies $\sqrt x \in \mathbb R$ which implies $x \in (0, \infty)$. On the other hand is we claim the domain is $\mathbb R$ i.e. we so $x$ can be any real number. then for $x < 0$ we have two possible square roots:  $ai$ and bi$ where $a^2 = |x|$ and $a = -b$. We could say pick the one where $a \ge 0$.  And if we want to say $x \in \mathbb C$ we would have to define a way of picking which of the two square roots we want.

In all of these though, choosing the domain, as well as the vaule of the range, is *not* a matter of answering a question.  It's a matter of making a choice in the definition of our function.

And we could choose anything we like.

Comment: Very good. In fact, I would go so far as: if we *defined* $\sqrt{bananas}=bananas$ and $bananas^2=bananas$, then we should add $bananas$ to this 'most all encompassing possible domain' as well.

Comment: Yeah,  less absurd is to define $\sqrt{\infty}$ = $\infty$ so the domain could be the extended reals.  Or if we define the square roots on vector spaces or $\mathbb R^n$ or any space or construct.  Ultimately this is a meaningless question.  But I don't want to yell at the *STUDENT* for asking a meaningless question.  I want to yell at the *TEACHER*.  But it's hard to get into *why* this is a meaningless question.

Comment: Agree 100 %.  I really cringe when I see these kinds of questions.

Comment: Also, the weird thing about this is not that the *domain* is hard to figure.  It's the definition of what what square root is.  As there are always two square roots, we must distinguish which one is THE square root. And in making that distinction ("the positive one") we are usually making assumptions of what the domain is in the first place (e.g. in order to pick "the positive one" we are assuming that the domain consists of positive and negative numbers in the first place.  i.e. were already assuming the domain IS the real numbers.)

Comment: thats ok but if the question above mentioned that the output mestb be real does the domain be R or [0 , infinity) and why ?

Comment: Well,  if $\sqrt {x}\in \mathbb R $ what does that say about $x $?

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is exactly why I think these kinds of questions "What is the domain of [some expression]?" are ill-posed.

I mean, in this case you at least have a $\sqrt{}$ which suggests we're dealing with numbers here, rather than, say $bananas$ ... but what would be the domain of $f(x)=x$? Why couldn't that contain $bananas$, for example?

In other words, I believe any question that asks for a domain should give some *initial* restriction as to what kind of structure we're dealing with in the first place, and hence what kinds of objects are at least *candidates* for the domain.

Better yet, I would really like to see a notion on the input side that is analogous to what the 'co-domain' is on the 'output side: something that tells us what we're dealing with, before we try and figure out which objects are actually 'covered' by the function.

(and another thing: 'co-domain' most likely is a contraction of 'converse domain' ... Russell and Whitehead defined the converse domain of a binary relation as the 'domain of its converse', i.e. inverse ... and in his 1920 'Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy' Russell still uses the term 'converse domain' to mean exactly that ... I have traced the term 'co-domain' back to at least 1922 when in "Mathematical Philosophy, a study of fate and freedom", Cassius Keyser uses the term 'codomain' to mean exactly what R&W meant by 'converse domain' ... but this is *not* how we use 'co-domain' nowadays, for the 'domain of the converse' is what we nowadays call the 'image' or 'range'.

We use 'codomain' instead as the 'structure' with 'candidates' that the function maps to ... so why not have a similar distinction on the input side, e.g. make some distinction between 'domain of discourse' (the 'structure' that we're talking about in the first place) and 'domain of definition' (the subset of the domain of discourse for which the function is actually defined) It would eliminate all this initial confusion regarding "what is the domain of ..." questions as I high-lighted at the beginning of my post.)

..ok, I'll get off my soap-box now ...

Comment: May you have a look on my question below, please?

Comment: @Stu $\sqrt{}$ is *defined* to only take positive numbers and always produce positive numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

How can you define $\{x\}$ for $x\in\mathbb C$?

By the traditional definition the domain of $\{\sqrt{x}\}^2$ should be the domain of $\sqrt{x}$, which is $[0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

May I add an another question please? Let $f: x\to (\sqrt{x})^2$:

$x\in \mathbb{R}_+,\quad (\sqrt{x})^2\in \mathbb{R}_+$

Now if $\mathcal{D}_f=\mathbb{R}$

For $x\geq 0$, nothing changes, but for $x<0$

$(\sqrt{x})^2= (\sqrt{-|x|})^2= \left(\sqrt{i^2|x|}\right)^2= (i\sqrt{|x|})^2=-|x|=x\in\mathbb{R}$ so$\quad f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$

And my question is Why we can't say $\mathcal{D}_f=\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Math.SE is not a forum, but a QA community. You are encouraged to post a separate question, but this area is for answers.